# Parsing 土曜日に予定がない

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 土曜日に予定がない

I don't think this に marks time because 予定がない is not something that happens. My closest guess is that it denotes 評価.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ない being the negative form of the verb ある, your sentence has the same basic structure as a sentence like this.

> 月曜日に試験がある。

This に clearly indicates a specific time when something happens. The difference, of course, is that the subject in your sentence is not an action or event, but a plan. But then again, this plan is one for **doing** something. People will understand this 予定 as **する**こと and think of some action or event when they hear someone say 予定がある or 予定がない. This must be making に acceptable enough.

While totally acceptable in everyday conversation, the following polite versions still don’t quite sound natural to me as standalone sentences.

> 土曜日に予定があります。
>
> 土曜日に予定がありません。

The following are totally unacceptable as スケジュール cannot be understood as the same as すること.

> x 土曜日にスケジュールがあります。
>
> x 土曜日にスケジュールがありません。

Comment: Is my comment under the first answer a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Nameless - I think so. ストライキが予定されている essentially means the same thing as ストライキがある. It goes well with the time-に.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you ask someone if they have any plans in a polite context? If the sentences above don't sound natural, wouldn't it also be unnatural to directly ask「今週末、予定はありますか？」or something along those lines?

Comment: @JansthcirlU - That sounds natural. You could also say 今週末は（何か）予定がありますか. It is the に that is making the sentences above somewhat unnatural.

Answer (score 3):

In this case「土曜日」(Saturday) is a time indication, so this usage of に is temporal. The word「予定」means schedule or plan, but it's also used to mean *plans* (i.e. things to do). Your sentence therefore translates to:

> I have no plans on Saturday.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct. ない by itself denotes a state rather than action, but when combined with 予定, it implies some action as a consequence of not having arranged for something. In this sense, 予定されている is state but ストライキが予定されている an action, so you can use it with に, as in ４月６日にストライキが予定されている.