# Why does 土曜日に予定があります sound off?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

From this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/94023/45630),

> While totally acceptable in everyday conversation, the following polite versions still don’t quite sound natural to me as standalone sentences.
>
> > 土曜日に予定があります。
> >
> > 土曜日に予定がありません。

> That (今週末、予定はありますか) sounds natural. You could also say 今週末は（何か）予定がありますか. It is the に that is making the sentences above somewhat unnatural.

It figures looking at the search results:

- [sentencesearch.neocities.org](https://sentencesearch.neocities.org/#%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)
- [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%20%23sentences)
- weblio.jp | [予定がある](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B) | [予定があります](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)  .

は is preferred over に, or sometimes no particle at all. However, に is used quite often.

Assuming context is not important, then my guess is that, as あります is あり + ます, あり is more along the lines of *to exist* rather *to happen*. Similarly, we say あり得る *possible to exist* and 起こり得る *possible to happen*. Under this reasoning, 土曜日に予定があり is bad but 土曜日に予定があって fine.

Comment: I don't really understand the distinction you're making between あり and あって at the end. They're just different forms of the same verb.

Comment: That’s precisely for the reason I said に is “acceptable”. 予定 *could* be understood as an event but it is not quite an event.

Comment: @aguijonazo Is 土曜日に予定があります natural if it can be understood as event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason they sound a bit off as standalone sentences compared to, say, 月曜日に試験があります is as follows. に as the time marker expects an event to be bound to a particular point of time, but 予定 is not concrete enough as an event. You have that plan now. What you have on Saturday is whatever you plan to **do**, not the plan itself. The listener can, and will, still make sense out of it by understanding 予定 as meaning すること as I said in the linked question, but that doesn’t necessarily make the sentence completely natural.

That said, there are times when に is the best, or least bad, choice in a subordinate clause. This happens because a time expression like 土曜日 being used as a standalone adverb with no particle seems detached in a subordinate clause, and は could add an unwanted sense of contrast.

> 土曜日**に**予定があるか彼に聞いてみよう。

When an added sense of contrast is not a problem, は is preferred.

> 土曜日**は**予定があるので行けません。

Whether an expression sounds natural or not is not a black-and-white matter. It is a function of multiple factors.

Comment: Why does 土曜日に予定がある sound more natural then? It's just ある in the polite form.

Comment: @Nameless - People have lower expectations for “correctness” in casual everyday conversation. That's one of the factors.